# How can I download attachments from a list in SharePoint using an API?

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint, automation

How can I download attachments from a list (not the documents of the page) in SharePoint using an API in Python?

I have a list with 60+ rows and the contents is added from a Power App form. Each row is a different entry and may or may not have an attachment.

I'm working on an automation process that will read each line of the list and enter it into SAP.
I can't seem to find an API that can get attachments from a list, they are all about getting them from the documents folder of the page.

Below is the site URL I'm using, and what the list looks like.

```
https://{site url}/sites/{group name}/Lists/{listname}/AllItems.aspx?e=3%3A32b71e288cd841f5b13422c0b99ffe89&at=9
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
function GetListItemAttachments() {
// Specify the Id of the Item that you want to fetch
var Itemid = 1;

$.ajax
({
    // _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl - will give absolute URL of the site where you are running the code.
    // You can replace this with other site URL where you want to apply the function

    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('List Name')/items(" + Itemid + ")/AttachmentFiles",
    method: "GET",
    headers:
       {
           // Accept header: Specifies the format for response data from the server.
           "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
       },
    success: function (data, status, xhr) {
        var dataresults = data.d.results;
        for (var i = 0; i < dataresults.length; i++) {
            alert(dataresults[i]["FileName"]);
        }
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        console.log("Failed");
    }
});
}
```

Read more: [Get All Attachments From List Item in SharePoint using REST API](https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/get-all-attachments-from-list-item-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api).

Comment: thanks for that @Allen_MSFT, I'm looking for a python API though.